# TYPO3: is there a way to access the image_zoom (enlarge on click) property of an image or asset via Typoscript?

Tags: image, typo3, zooming, assets, typoscript

Is there a way to access the `image_zoom` (enlarge on click) property of an image or asset via TypoScript? Unfortunately not accessible in a data wrap like `{file:current:image_zoom}` because this property is "not found in file reference or original file". Is there another way to access it, e.g. via a select query? Thx in advance!

[image: screenshot editor view image_zoom / click to enlarge]

Comment: What exactly do you want to archive? In Fluid you can maybe use `{data.image_zoom}` regarding your context.

Comment: I needed to give a special css class to my lib. object if zoom_image was activated to  initiate photoswipe

Answer (score 1):

`image_zoom` is a property of the content element (table `tt_content`), not of the file or filereference. So, you won't get access to this property via your file.

Comment: thx, that was it. So for others you can do it like "stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="zoom_{field:image_zoom}">|</div>"